I am using Azure Function App and I am trying to deploy a function but No HTTP trigger found is the error I'm getting. Why?
I am using azure functions app to deploy a function from my VS Code. I have checked for the local.settings.json and I've added
AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags: EnableWorkerIndexing
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" these settings in my json too.
Also I have checked for dependencies and all dependencies are fullfilled.
from azure.search.documents.models import VectorizableTextQuery
import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

These are the imports I'm making for my code, can someone tell me why this problem is happening?
2024-07-18  [Information] Loading functions metadata
2024-07-18  [Information] Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-07-18  [Information] 1 functions found (Custom)
2024-07-18  [Information] 0 functions loaded
2024-07-18  [Information] Loading functions metadata
2024-07-18  [Information] Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-07-18  [Information] 1 functions found (Custom)
2024-07-18  [Information] 0 functions loaded


10:39:06 AM : Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
10:39:06 AM : Removing existing manifest file
10:39:06 AM : Running pip install...
10:39:20 AM : Syncing triggers...
10:39:22 AM : Querying triggers...
10:39:26 AM : No HTTP triggers found.

These are the logs which I have provided and you can check from the logs that there is no problem with the code as the function is working perfect on local but when it is deployed the HTTP trigger is not working. Log is No HTTP triggers found.
Can someone help me with this problem and tell me if I'm missing something? Requirements.txt local.setting.json host.json

Can you please share your complete function code

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
logging.info('HTTP trigger    .')
name = req.params.get('name')
if not name:
try:
req_body = req.get_json()
except ValueError:
pass
else:
name = req_body.get('name')
if name:
return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}.")
else:
return func.HttpResponse(
"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.
status_code=200
)

This is my function

{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
}
}
This is my host.json

{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
}
}
This is my local.settings

I am using default code with the same imports alike you.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import os
from azure.search.documents.models import VectorizableTextQuery
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

You need to add the below packages in requirements.txt file.
azure-functions
azure-search-documents
azure-core

By doing this, I am able to deploy successfully to function app.

I can see the function in portal and able to access it too.


Your last two images are not visible I don't know why can you reshare?

Here you go https://i.imgur.com/cU6EeIe.png, https://i.imgur.com/O0Gcjmo.png

Are you able to deploy successfully?

I've added these dependencies in requirements.txt but still it is not working. I don't know what the problem is

Are you using any other packages in your code? Also please share the screenshot of the environment variables present in function app

Okay let me share my host.json and local.setting.json to you

Please check I've added the images in my question itself by editing it

Please help me out with this issue

please share this with me. Local settings is being used for local development only. The issue you are facing is mainly because of requirements.txt file. Can you share your requirements.txt please

azure-functions
azure-core
azure-search-documents==11.5.0
psycopg2
PyYAML

Use like this

About environment variables, I'm using YAML file to upload and use and consume every settings in azure. And only the imports I have added in the question is creating the issues as it is unable to find specifically azure-search-document and I dont know why this issue is happening

I tried like this too as you stated but it didn't worked

Modify your requirements.txt to azure-functions, azure-search-documents, azure-core, psycopg, PyYAML.

In your requirements.txt file you are using incorrect module name which is psycopg2 instead use psycopg

Tried earlier also anyways just tried but it didn't worked ):

Yes it is also not working

Can you share the screenshot of your latest requirements.txt file instead of text. This issue is only due to the presence of incorrect package reference in requirements.txt

See I've edited my question and placed the screenshot of requirement.txt file there, Please help me

Also please share the screenshot of your project folder structure like this

It is for real exactly as same as yours just difference is I have 3 different function apps file.

I believe the error is coming from those files because if you create a single http trigger function with the given code in it and add the packages in requirement file then you will be able to deploy successfully

Also please note if you have multiple functions with either different trigger or same trigger then the code for all the kind of functions should be in a single function_app.py file. So while creating multiple functions use func new command in terminal, you will see that it will add the function code in the same function_app.py file

I had one function only. For testing I added another functioon but it didn't worked either.

Can you try to deploy using func azure functionapp publish <func-app-name> command
